# Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found Cordova 3.5

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

I am following [this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) tutorial to implement Push Notifications into my PhoneGap application. However I keep getting the following error in XCode:

```
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] CDVPlugin class PushPlugin (pluginName: PushPlugin) does not exist.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.425 Clubbed In[336:60b] ERROR: Plugin 'PushPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2014-06-03 22:50:38.427 Clubbed In[336:60b] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 158] FAILED pluginJSON = [
"PushPlugin1224815266",
"PushPlugin",
"register",
[
 {
  "alert" : "true",
  "ecb" : "onNotificationAPN",
  "sound" : "true",
  "badge" : "true"
 }
]
```

I have put the 4 delegate/plugin files into my project's plugin folder successfully. In addition, I have added the PushNotification.js and referenced it correctly. I also have the following feature tags in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting this error? I am pretty sure that I correctly manually installed this PushPlugin.

In the plugins folder should I include a folder called com.plugin.PushPlugin, then put the 4 files within that?

Any help would truly be appreciated. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time...

Thanks!

Comment: Reinstall the plugin manually..

Comment: What do you mean? Installing it is by putting the files. Look at the link. I don't think recopying the files will do anything. I am using non-CLI version btw. I am the same person as OP, just different account.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I just find the solution. I've replaced my init code with:

```
var pushNotification = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "1234567890"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    pushNotification.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log("registration event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    pushNotification.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log("notification event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        pushNotification.finish(function () {
            console.log('finish successfully called');
        });
    });

    pushNotification.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("push error");
    });
```

[PushPlugin not found, or is not a CDVPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430445/pushplugin-not-found-or-is-not-a-cdvplugin)